# Why takeLeading redux-sagas isn't working

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm not quite sure why `takeLeading` isn't working for me (takeLeading is supposed to take the first call and ignore subsequent calls until the first is returned). It's calling the same call 3 separate times like a `takeEvery` with the same parameters from 3 separate components in their `useEffect(() => {getApiWatcher(params)}, [])` on mount hook. It appears those don't return before the second is called either so I know it's not 3 uniquely separate calls.

```
function getApi(params) {
    console.log('GET CALL') // called 3 times in console and network tab
    return Api.doCall(
        `API/${params.number}/${params.type}`,
        'GET'
    );
}

function* getApiActionEffect(action) {
    const { payload } = action;
    try {
        const response = yield call(getApi, payload);
        yield put(getApiSuccess({ data: response.data, status: response.status }));
    } catch (e) {
        yield put(getApiError(e.response));
    }
}

export function* getApiActionWatcher() {
    yield takeLeading( // should make sure only first call is made and subsequent are ignored
        GET_API_WATCHER,
        getApiActionEffect
    );
}


// action
export function getApiWatcher(payload) {
    return { type: GET_API_WATCHER, payload };
}

// passed dispatch as props
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => bindActionCreators( { getApiWatcher, }, dispatch ); 

// root saga
export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([... getApiActionWatcher(),...])
}
```

There is a lot more code involved so I'm not creating a sample jsfiddle, but ideas for what could potentially be going wrong are what I'm looking for! Might have over looked something.

Comment: Repro on codesandbox would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there were duplicate imported functions in the root saga. For example:

```
// root saga
export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([
        ... getApiActionWatcher(),...
        ... getApiActionWatcher(),...
    ])
}
```

Removing the duplicates solved the issue. It also removed other duplicate calls I wasn't working on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle every `GET_API_WATCHER` action then you better `takeEvery` redux-saga `helper`.

And [docs](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#takeleadingpattern-saga-args) says that task spawned with `takeLeading` blocks others tasks until it's done.

Comment: yes, takeLeading is what I want. It's acting like a takeEvery when it shouldn't

Comment: i've edited the question to be more clear, sorry about any confusion

Comment: Then it's difficult to say why it happens without reproducible example.

Comment: Understood, it works in certain parts of the application and not in others, it's very odd and i don't understand why. Would you be willing to delete your answer ? just so people aren't thinking it's answered

Answer (score 0):

`takeLeading` is working as intended. The calls to `getApi` instantly returns.

The only way your code would work the way you want it to is if `getApi` returns a Promise. If `getApi()` were to return a Promise, the `getApiActionEffect` would block until the Promise resolved.

Comment: I was thinking that, but it shows the other queries still having resolved in the network tab